# Listar campos y documentos mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Soy nuevo por mongoDB y estoy intentando listar los campos existentes en un documento.

Las colecciones las he listado de la siguiente manera:

```
base_datos.list_collection_names()
```

¿Hay alguna manera también mediante un comando sencillo para listar los campos de un documento?

Comment: No, no existe un comando que liste los campos de los documentos, porque los documentos de una colección pueden tener diferentes campos unos con otros. Recuerda que estás trabajando con base de datos noSQL. Las cosas que haces en SQL no las puedes hacer en MongoDB

Comment: Podrías usar un proceso de [`mapReduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/map-reduce/) para lograr el cometido.

Comment: Una de lasa maneras que he hecho en python para consultar lo que comentaba es hacer un find de todo, y luego pasar ese find a dataframe o lista y visualizar esos campos. Pero quería saber si existía esa posibilidad en MongoDB directamente

Answer (score 0):

Para listar los campos de un documento se utiliza lo siguiente:

```
Object.keys(db.collection_name.findOne())
```